# End-of-file trigger error

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, triggers

I have this code:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER avg_elo_trigger
     AFTER
       INSERT OR DELETE 
     ON participants_list
BEGIN
     UPDATE eventss e2
     SET average_elo = (SELECT Round(Avg(p.elo)) FROM participants_list pl 
                                                 join eventss e on e.event_id = pl.event_id 
                                                 join players p on p.player_id = pl.player_id 
                                                 WHERE e.event_id = :P20_EVENT_ID)
     WHERE e2.event_id = :P20_EVENT_ID
END;
/
```

I'm getting error end-of-file on line 9 and I don't have idea what's the problem. Code between `BEGIN` and `END` works out of trigger.

Comment: You're missing a `;` after `WHERE e2.event_id = :P20_EVENT_ID`.

Comment: What development tool are you using that reports `error end-of-file on line 9`? There should be a multi-line compilation error stack with an `ORA-00933: SQL command not properly ended` and a `PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol "end-of-file" when expecting one of the following:` followed by a long list of keywords. Reporting compilation errors is a basic function of dev tools so I would strongly suggest finding one that does this properly.

Comment: Also, what is `:P20_EVENT_ID`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have the missing semicolon.

But you can also simplify the query:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER avg_elo_trigger
     AFTER INSERT OR DELETE 
     ON participants_list
BEGIN
    UPDATE eventss e
        SET average_elo = (SELECT Round(Avg(p.elo))
                           FROM participants_list pl join
                                players p
                                on p.player_id = pl.player_id 
                           WHERE pl.event_id = e.event_id
                         )
        WHERE e2.event_id = :new.P20_EVENT_ID;
END;
```

Notes:

- The `events` table is not needed in the subquery.
- The correlation can be to `participants_list`.
- The correlation can be to the outer table, rather than repeating the constant.

Comment: That `:P20_EVENT_ID` still looks like a problem.